# How to use nested query using &or with &any in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm learning `mongoDB` queries and have a problem given my collection looks like:

```
"filename": "myfile.png",
"updatedCoordinates": [
{
    "xmin": 537.640869140625,
    "xmax": 1049.36376953125,
    "ymin": 204.90736389160156,
    "ymax": 714.813720703125,
    "label": "LABEL_0",
    "status": "UNCHANGED"
},
{
    "xmin": 76.68355560302734,
    "xmax": 544.8860473632812,
    "ymin": 151.90313720703125,
    "ymax": 807.1371459960938,
    "label": "LABEL_0",
    "status": "UNCHANGED"
}],

"predictedCoordinates": [
{
    "xmin": 537.640869140625,
    "xmax": 1049.36376953125,
    "ymin": 204.90736389160156,
    "ymax": 714.813720703125,
    "status": "UNCHANGED",
    "label": "LABEL_0"
}
]
```

and the eligible values of `status` are: `UNCHANGED, CHANGED, UNDETECTED`

How would I query: **Get all the in instances from the db where `status == CHANGED / UNDECTED` for `ANY` of the values inside either `updatedCoordinates` or `predictedCoordinates`** ?

It means that if status of minimum of 1 entry inside either updated or predicted is set to changed or undetected, it's eligible for my query.

I tried:

```
{"$or":[{"updatedCoordinates.status": "CHANGED"}, {"predictedCoordinates.status": "CHANGED"}]}
```

With Python `dict`, I can query as:

```
def find_eligible(single_instance:dict):
    for key in ["predictedCoordinates", "updatedCoordinates"]:
        for i in single_instance[key]:
            if i["status"] in ["CHANGED", "UNDETECTED]: return True
    return False
```

But retrieving 400K instances first just to filter a few ones is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "updatedCoordinates.status": {
        "$in": [
          "CHANGED",
          "UNDETECTED"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "predictedCoordinates.status": {
        "$in": [
          "CHANGED",
          "UNDETECTED"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Mongodb playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qda-G5L1mbR

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of Mongo's [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) allows access to nested values in arrays / objects, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  "updatedCoordinates.status": "CHANGED"
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l_5wqFF2-DU)

Comment: But how do I next the two `$or`?

Comment: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Txxovdeau3X) ?

Comment: yes, but with an `$or` between `Changed, Undetected` too,